# Filter a List By Category - Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a list from firebase which I want to filter and display the specializations under each category. When I do console log both the categories and specializations are retrieved, but I can’t figure out what I need to be doing to render specialization in UI when category is selected. Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks. Below is my work:

[image: Project Output]

[image: Database collection Design]

category.JSON

{
  "-Lq2PAU_P-fPniAMrQ85" : {
    "name" : "test"
  },
  "accountingFinance" : {
    "name" : "Accounting and Finance"
  },
  "assuranceAudit" : {
    "name" : "Assurance and Audit"
  },
  "riskManagement" : {
    "name" : "Risk Management"
  },
  "taxation" : {
    "name" : "Taxation"
  }
}

categories.JSON

```
{
  "accountingFinance" : [ null, "Accounting Management Information Systems", "Accounting Records Maintenance", "Accounts Preparation", "Accountancy / Finance Training" ],
  "assuranceAudit" : [ null, "Asset Management Review", "Assurance / Audit Training", "Climate Change / Sustainability Audit", "Enviromental Audit" ],
  "riskManagement" : [ null, "Acturial Service", "Enterprise Risk Management", "Fraud Risk Management", "Political Risk Management" ],
  "taxation" : [ null, "Business Income Tax", "Capital Gains Tax", "Corporation Tax", "Employee Tax (PAYE)", "Export Incentives" ]
}
```

HTML Markup

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="list-group">
                                    <a 
                                        *ngFor="let c of (category$ | async)" 
                                        routerLink="/admin/expert-category" [queryParams]="{ category: c.key }"
                                        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                                        [class.active]="category === c.key">
                                        {{ c.name }}
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let categories of filteredCategories; let i = index">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <!--<div class="card-body">-->
                                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
                                                        <li class="list-group-item">{{ categories }}</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                <!--/div>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div  *ngIf="(i+1) % 4 === 0" class="-w-100"></div>
                                    </ng-container>     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Service.ts

```
getCategories(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list('/categories')
    .snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions =>
        actions.map(data => ({ key: data.key, ...data.payload.val() }))
    ));
  }

  getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list('/category')
    .snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(category =>
        category.map(cat => {
            const key = cat.key;
            const payload = cat.payload.val();
            return { key, ...payload };
          })),
        );
  }
```

Component.ts file

```
export class ExpertCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  category$;
  category: string;
  closeResult: string;
  filteredCategories: any[] = [];
  specialization: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private modalService: NgbModal) {

      this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(specialization => {
        this.specialization = specialization;
        console.log(this.specialization);
        route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
          this.category = params.get('category');

          this.filteredCategories = (this.category) ? this.specialization.filter(s => s.category === this.category) : this.specialization;
          console.log(this.filteredCategories);
          });
      });

      this.category$ = this.categoryService.getAll();
  }
```

I don't get any errors at the moment except for an empty array in the console when I select a category.

Comment: Best way is to use custom pipe to filter any thing.

Comment: @Mises Not according to their documentation: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: I do not see `category` in your JSON example but you are using it in (`s.category`)

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/mises543/sorting-list/src/master/src/app/shared/pipes/filter-sort.pipe.ts this pipe sort by Category/Query/Sort alphabetical by title and time.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Custom pipe is not an allredy build one.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Work see ? https://sorting-list-angular.web.app/library

Comment: HOw many items are we expecting through this call?

Comment: I'm actually implementing what I've learnt from a tutorial in my own project. I'm a newbie at this so kindly bare with me if am slow. This is my second JSON example for s.category

Comment: {
  "-Lq2PAU_P-fPniAMrQ85" : {
    "name" : "test"
  },
  "accountingFinance" : {
    "name" : "Accounting and Finance"
  },
  "assuranceAudit" : {
    "name" : "Assurance and Audit"
  },
  "riskManagement" : {
    "name" : "Risk Management"
  },
  "taxation" : {
    "name" : "Taxation"
  }
}

Comment: I apologize for the awful code format. How do I format code in a comment?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment  sorting-list-angular.web.app/library is close to what i want to achieve, but I can't see any code. Would you kindly point me to where i can get it.

Comment: Going to try to add some code over the weekend

Comment: @Maihan Nijat When you mentioned (s.category) not being in my JSON file I realized  I'm having UI rendering issues because of bad database design. I have edited my code to include the model, and requesting if you could look at it and offer guidance. I haven't found any solutions yet.Thanks.

Comment: @Mises I added a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-obs-vs-pipe?file=src/app/app.component.ts) demonstrating why it isn't recommended to use a pipe for this.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Good to know but still my pipe is pure and trigger only on any sortBy or filter change. So it will not destroy user experience.

Comment: @Mises That is true, but the docs say the pipe needs to be impure because it references object properties. Yours doesn't as you have them hard-coded in the pipe itself(i.e. `title`, `uploaded`). That is something important to highlight.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Yeah i know and there is an option to make a class final ? Like to make it unextendable ?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Becouse some one can extend his impure pipe by my sorting pipe.

Comment: @Mises See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306)

Comment: @E.Ogony If you tried to apply the below to your code and it didn't work, please update your question with the details. Better yet would be to provide a StackBlitz of your own so that I could work through the changes you would need to get things working.

Comment: @ peinearydevelopment I appreciate your concern. Please find the link to the project. If it's not too much to ask, would you give an example that uses a service to retrieve data from firebase DB. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-99tvpd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsx641) with the code.

There are some minor modifications to the html you provided above. There is also a 'firebase' mock so you can see that I'm using the data you provided above as well. You will probably want to look there for the full example.

Also, a lot of the methods utilized below are from amazing speakers like [Deborah Kurata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck) and others.

In regards to your question about filtering though,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseStub } from './firebase.stub';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  private selectedCategory = new BehaviorSubject<string>('accountingFinance');

  category$: Observable<any>;
  selectedCategory$ = this.selectedCategory.asObservable();
  categories$: Observable<any>;


  constructor(private firebaseStub: FirebaseStub) {
    this.categories$ = this.selectedCategory$
                           .pipe(
                             mergeMap(selectedCategory => this.firebaseStub
                                                              .categories$
                                                              .pipe(map((category: any) => category[selectedCategory]))
                            )
                          );

    this.category$ = firebaseStub.category$
                                 .pipe(
                                   tap((category: any) => this.selectedCategory.next('accountingFinance')),
                                   map(categoryObj => Object.keys(categoryObj).map((key,index) => categoryObj[key].name))
                                  );
  }
}
```

I tried to maintain your naming conventions though they are a little hard for me to follow. You will see that `categories$` is the filtered list of categories based on the full list received from 'firebase' and the `selectedCategory`. In general, I've seen the selectedCategory value come from a dropdown in the UI, and when the user selects a new value, that select would fire off a method to update the selectedCategory(by calling `next` on it). I have hard-coded a value here again, as this isn't the main thrust of your question.

The filtering is then done through the rxjs `mergeMap` operator. It takes the latest value emitted by the `selectedCategory$` observable passes that to the `map` operator that is `pipe`d through Firebase's `categories$` observable. The mapped filtered categories are returned as the component's `categories$` observable.

**UPDATE**

Just in reference to some of the comments on the initial question. I created a very small/quick [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-obs-vs-pipe?file=src/app/app.component.ts) demonstrating some of inefficiencies using an impure pipe approach. If you open the Console in the preview pane, you can see how many times the impure pipe is invoked even relating to completely unrelated actions. Each time it gets called, the ui gets rerendered.